# Can we get back the orange quote formatting?

Tags: feature-request, formatting, user-interface

I've just noticed today that the quote box is not orange, but grey instead. And it's less noticeable.

[image: New blockquote]

It seems dull. At these times we need to color our world with hope.

**Can we get back the old orange blockquote? And with more opaque background.**

Comment: The corresponding MSE post proposing (and then implementing) the change: [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/335251). The feedback to it - including a highly upvoted answer by an RPG.SE contributor, and comments by at least 2 of us mods - seems to have been largely ignored, as the change was made anyway (with the "update" to the question solely addressing the third-highest answer, and entirely ignoring the issues pointed out in the all the other answers - including the two answers with a higher score than that one).

Comment: @V2Blast So, exactly the kind of quality community outreach that SE is becoming known for?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you use the mobile web version (not the application), quotes are still yellow/gold. You can even use this on a desktop as there is a button at the *very* bottom of the page labelled "mobile". It's not even close to a good alternative, but I thought I'd mention it